# emacs 26.3 gets package-install-from-archive: HTTPS support could not find ‘ssl’ library error

Tags: emacs, openssl

I'm running emacs 26.3 (installed with Ubuntu 20.10). I'm trying to run the package manager. When I select a package to install (realgud), I get the message:

```
package-install-from-archive: HTTPS support could not find ‘ssl’ library.
```

Any idea how to fix that? I think I have the ssl library.
If I execute:

```
% apt-file search libssl | grep libssl-dev
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
libssl-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libssl.pc
libssl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libssl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/changelog.gz
libssl-dev: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/copyright
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/README
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/Makefile
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/README
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/accept.cnf
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/client-arg.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/client-conf.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/cmod.cnf
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/connect.cnf
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/descrip.mms
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/intca.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/root.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/saccept.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/sconnect.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/server-arg.c.gz
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/server-cmod.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/server-conf.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/server-ec.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/server.pem.gz
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/shared.opt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/bio/static.opt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/README
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/apps.cnf
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/ckey.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/intkey.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/mkacerts.sh
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/mkxcerts.sh
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/rootkey.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/skey.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/apps/skey2.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/ca.cnf
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/mkcerts.sh
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/ocspquery.sh
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/certs/ocsprun.sh
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cacert.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cakey.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_comp.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_ddec.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_dec.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_denc.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_enc.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_sign.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_sign2.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_uncomp.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/cms_ver.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/comp.txt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/encr.txt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/sign.txt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/signer.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/cms/signer2.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/engines/e_chil.txt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/evp/Makefile
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/evp/aesccm.c.gz
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/evp/aesgcm.c.gz
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/pkcs12/pkread.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/pkcs12/pkwrite.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/cacert.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/cakey.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/encr.txt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/sign.txt
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/signer.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/signer2.pem
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/smdec.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/smenc.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/smsign.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/smsign2.c
libssl-doc: /usr/share/doc/libssl-dev/demos/smime/smver.c
```

Comment: Is this the first or only package you tried to install after you set up MELPA (see https://github.com/realgud/realgud#user-content-setup) returning the above error message? Maybe also check https://melpa.org/#installing which explains how to test TLS support–does this work?

Comment: Yes, I had followed the user-content-setup. It used to work, but I haven't used it in over a year.
The melpa.org/#installing does not mention TLS. However https://melpa.org/#/getting-started does. I tried the test and got:
eww: Symbol’s value as variable is void: cl-struct-url-tags
A search for cl-struct-url-tags turned up nothing.